# Populate text box on api request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to populate text boxes as soon as I type in a valid zip code (5 digits checking with regex on keyup event). How would I make this possible? This is my code so far where I've gotten stuck:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get ZipCode Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <label>Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zipcode" value=""><br/ >
    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" value=""><br/ >
    <label>State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="state" value=""><br/ >
<div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$("#zipcode").keyup(function(e){

        var zipcode = $("#zipcode").val();
        var googleAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

        if (zipcode.length == 5)
        {
            $.getJSON(googleAPI + zipcode + function(data){
                $("#city").val(data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name);
                $("#state").val(data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name);
            });
        }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding unnecessary + in json request see `googleAPI + zipcode + function(data){`, instead + you should use `,` see the below code:

```js
$("#zipcode").keyup(function(e){

        var zipcode = $("#zipcode").val();
        var googleAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

        if (zipcode.length == 5)
        {
            $.getJSON(googleAPI + zipcode ,function(data){ 
            
                $("#city").val(data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name);
                $("#state").val(data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name);
            });
        }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get ZipCode Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <label>Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zipcode" value=""><br/ >
    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" value=""><br/ >
    <label>State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="state" value=""><br/ >
<div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not notice that at all. Thanks for pointing it out, Omi.